# How can I change my LDAP configs to Spring Security realization?

Tags: spring-security, ldap

I have this LDAP configuration:

```
Hashtable env = new Hashtable();

            env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
            env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://.....");
            env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
            env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "login);
            env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);

            // Create the initial context 
            DirContext ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);
            boolean result = ctx != null;
```

How can I change this configuration for Spring Security realization?

```
auth.ldapAuthentication().....
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this sample code as a template. In my case, the LDAP provider URL is `ldap://localhost:1389/dc=example,dc=com` and the user entries have the following DN pattern: `uid={0},ou=people,dc=example,dc=com`. This means that the `uid` attribute will be used as the username.

```
LdapContextSource ctxSrc = new LdapContextSource();
ctxSrc.setUrl("ldap://localhost:1389");
ctxSrc.setBase("dc=example,dc=com");
ctxSrc.setUserDn("login");
ctxSrc.setPassword("password");
ctxSrc.afterPropertiesSet();

auth
  .ldapAuthentication()
  .contextSource(ctxSrc)
  .userSearchBase("ou=people")
  .userSearchFilter("(uid={0})");
```